# Fall back to local jQuery in case Google CDN fails to serve it

Tags: feature-request, javascript, jquery

I was clicking around Meta Stack Overflow earlier and suddenly ran into a page with a big red error message at the top, "Meta Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.":

[image: Meta Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.]

Looking at the error log, I saw `Undefined ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

[image: Undefined ReferenceError: $ is not defined]

So it looks like [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) failed to load. Being at work when this happened, I got distracted by something work-related and by the time I came back to continue my investigation of this, I realized I had accidentally closed the browser tab, so I didn't get a chance to look at the developer tools "Network" tab and confirm my suspicion that the Google [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) failed to serve jQuery. But it still seems likely. Especially considering the error is coming from "stub", which is included right after jQuery:

[image: jQuery including]

So, since you're not using an asynchronous script loader here, it would be easy to implement a piece of code that falls back to a local copy of JavaScript code in the case where Google's CDN fails. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/content/js/query.min.js"><\/script>')
```

Is it a good idea?

Comment: Doh, I'm sure this dupe showed up in the "may already have been asked" box and I just completely failed to see it...